# How to manage lazy coworker?

Tags: colleagues, relationships

I have a coworker in my workplace which is a web-developer. He is not so interested in his job and in case of problems in his daily tasks, he stops his job somehow and waits till the problem resolves.
We have many problems in our workplace (which should not be like this) such as problems in the air conditioning system, loose internet connection and etc.
I also experience the same situation but he is always impose negative bias and his interrupts during the work lead to delay in delivery of our tasks.
How should I handle this without bothering him that have no side-effect on my job? Should I  report this to our direct manager or not (since if he understands that it happened by me it will have bad effect in our relationships)?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere our job is linked so delay and low performance of him will lead to poor view of my performance. Still wait for him to make my situation worse?

Comment: So, to be clear, he stops working when the A/C goes off?

Comment: What kind of team environment are you in? Do you do daily stand-ups to report progress (which will quickly make it obvious who's doing the work)? Do you have source control (your contributions will also be obvious)? Are you able to get a one-on-one with your leader/manager? This guy is a project risk, and in most places it's your responsibility to indicate project risks to management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not your task to manage a coworker, it the the manager's job.
So, do your job and if the coworker should help you and doesn't; you need to report him to the management.
Yes, "need to report". Because this coworker jeopardize the good fonctionning of the company.

If your question is about how to deal personally ( at your level) with the coworker, you should ask "How to deal with lazy cowroker".